# What is the relationship between order of object and verb and the position of adverbs?

Tags: naturalism, syntax

I've been researching ways to make conlangs more naturalistic. So far, sources such as WALS and a linguist YouTuber Colin Gorrie have stated the [relationship between object-verb order and adjective-noun order.](https://wals.info/chapter/97) But what about *adverbs?* Do adverbs tend to mimic the position of the adjective?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the site behind [the link you provided](https://wals.info/chapter/97) argues against any correlation of object-verb order and adj-noun order.

> The order of adjective and noun is often claimed to correlate with the order of object and verb. [...]
> [T]he data provide no basis for thinking that OV languages have any stronger preference for AdjN order than VO languages do.

However, verb-adverb and verb-object order are correlated. [Dryer (1992) "The Greenbergian word order correlations"](https://doi.org/10.1353/lan.1992.0028) (English, restricted access) states

> ADVERB. Although manner adverbs and other adverbs often pattern similarly, I consider only manner adverbs here, because many other kinds of adverbs are interpretable as sentence adverbs and exhibit
> greater flexibility of word order in many languages. Table 10 shows that
> manner adverbs overwhelmingly precede the verb in OV languages and generally follow
> the verb in VO languages.

From the table one can see that 89% of the OV languages also position the manner adverb before the verb, and
76% of the VO languages position the manner adverb after the verb.

So if you want to make your language more natural, the natural place for adverbs will be the same as the object if seen from the verb.
But I would strongly discourage you from restraining the position of the adverb too much. Even in English, which has an overall fairly strict word order, adverbs can move around in the sentence and all languages I know at least provide a way to move adverbs more front or more behind than usual.